# CMAKE - Custom Target

Tags: c, build, cmake

I want to make several target for build purpose. I have a project structure

```
src
- library in c
test
-test code for lib
example
-example code for lib
```

I want to build using

```
cmake 
make lib
make test
make example
```

Is this possbile? I tried with custom target but I couldn't

Comment: CMake isn't just used to generate Makefiles, it can also generate other build types. There may be a way to add custom targets to the makefile, but it wouldn't be a good idea. Instead, you can control the generation of certain targets within cmake via flags.

Comment: `I tried with custom target but I couldn't` - Show us what **exactly** have you tried. Building library/executable is a basic thing with CMake which is described in almost all tutorials. Same for adjusting dependencies between targets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`add_executable()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_executable.html) / [`add_library()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html) – each target will create a make target.

Typically there's a `CMakeLists.txt` (= Root file) in the project root and one in each source directory. This gives you a nice & clean project structure.

This sounds more work than it actually is …

```
<<Project Dir>>
|
+- CMakeLists.txt
|
+- src/
|  |
|  +- CMakeLists.txt
|  |
|  +- library in c
|
+- test/
|  |
|  +- CMakeLists.txt
|  |
|  +- test code for lib
|
+- example/
   |
   +- CMakeLists.txt
   |
   +- example code for lib
```

### CMakeLists.txt (Project Root)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0) # Or what you can use
project(Example VERSION 0.1)

# Add each subdir
add_subdirectory("src")
add_subdirectory("test")
add_subdirectory("example")
```

### src/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(lib Src1.c Src2.c)
```

### test/CMakeList.txt

**Note:** The target `test` is reserved and will run your tests (ctest)

```
add_executable(tests Test1.c Test2.c)
```

### example/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(example1 Example1.c)
target_link_libraries(example1 lib)

add_executable(example2 Example2.c)
target_link_libraries(example2 lib)
```

---

## Usage

Instead of running Cmake from project root, better do an out-of-source buid:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
make # Will build all targets (you can also do make example etc).
```

Now everything generated / local is within `build` and the proejct stays clean. You typically want to add that directory to eg. `.gitignore`.

Building per target:

```
make tests
make example1
make example1
make lib
# ...
```

You can make a target that builds `example1` and `example2` too. CMake can do almost everything.

## Dokumentation

- [CMake Dokumentation (latest)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/)
- [CMake Tutorial](https://cmake.org/cmake-tutorial/)